# Mac OS app options for SQL editor with JDBC or ODBC support

Tags: mac, editing, sql

Mac OS options for SQL editor with JDBC or ODBC support?

Answer (score 1):

I currently use:

- [SQirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/)
- [Maven](http://www.cutedgesystems.com/software/Maven/)

Answer (score 0):

My employer produces a free, simple, proof-of-concept [HTML5-based SQL client](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/HTML5ODBCExplorerSampleProg) which can be used against any ODBC data source on the web-browser host machine, through the HTML5 WebDB-to-ODBC Bridge we also produce (linked from that page).  These components are free, for Mac, Windows, and more.

This can be used with any ODBC Driver on Mac OS X, including those we produce [for many databases](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc/) (which are free for trial and evaluation, but not forever).